# Зачем нужен отрицательный margin?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но мне на него ответили так, как будто я уже выучил и знаю что такое bootstrap. Я понятия не имею что это, и зачем это. Я месяц учу HTML & CSS и в каждом из уроков в курсах говориться об отрицательных margin, о не понятном мне блоке .row. Я пробовал использовать его, но я так и не понял зачем оно надо. Объясните пожалуйста что такое .row и зачем нужны отрицательные margin пожалуйста

Comment: не надо начинать изучение какого-либо фреймворка не зная основ. Вы сначала просто изучите html и css. Потом уже переходите к бутстрапу. Очевидно нужно значть, что такое margin в принципе, и то что он может быть как положительным, так и отрицательным. Отрицательный может потребоваться для сдвига элемента за границы контейнера, или для невелирования паддинга в родительском контейнере. В общем ничего особенного в этом нет. И начните учить HTML/CSS с основ, а не с того, что вы там сейчас учите, потому что учите вы явно не то. Если у вас каждый урок про `.row` то явно курс по бутстрап и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

1. .row - это название класса. Поскольку row в переводе с ангельского - "строка", следовательно тот, кто создал этот класс, так обозначил стилизацию каких-то строк.

в HTML: `<div class="row"></div>`

в CSS: `.row { какой-то стиль, который будет применен к div }`

Конкретно в bootstrap этот класс используют так: 
[Система сеток в Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

2. Отрицательные margin используют для того, чтобы сдвинуть элемент в сторону, противоположную указанной, хотя во многих случаях - это не слишком хорошая практика.

Comment: "во многих случаях - это не слишком хорошая практика" - в каких?

Comment: В тех случаях, когда можно обойтись без него.

Comment: "В тех случаях, когда можно обойтись без него" - я имею ввиду, что изучать природу поведения блоков, например, гораздо правильнее, чем бездумно использовать отрицательный margin просто потому, что захотелось подвинуть элемент.